# Adding custom markers dynamically to map using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I would like to let users add custom markers on a map with a description for each marker. Any tips, links to any tutorials would be really useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can register a function to 'click' event on your map. When the user click on it, the mark is added automatically.

Try something like this:

```
// 'map' is your map created using new OpenLayers.Map(options)

markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
markers.id = "Markers";
map.addLayer(markers);

map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
      //var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
      var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
      var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
   var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
   var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('images/mark.png', size, offset);   
   var markerslayer = map.getLayer('Markers');

   markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon));

   });
```

Pretty simple, but I think that you can understand it :)

Answer (score 5):

i tried @Fran 's solution but it didnt work for me.  so i adapted  [this example from openlayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/mouse-position.html) so that i could accomplish 2 things:

1. save latitude and longitude of marker position
2. place a marker by clicking on the openlayers map

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" debug="true">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
       <title>MousePosition Control</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css">
       <script src="../OpenLayers.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var map;
           function init(){
               var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
               var proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
               var projmerc = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
               var layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Street Map");
               map.addLayers([layerOSM]);
               if (!map.getCenter()) map.zoomToMaxExtent();
               map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) { 
                   var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = 'MOUSE POSITION '+position;
                   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel( this.events.getMousePosition(e) );
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTG").innerHTML = 'lonlat => '+lonlat;
                   var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTrans").innerHTML = 'lonlatTransf => '+lonlatTransf;
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatDouble").innerHTML = 'lonlat => '+lonlat;
               });

               map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
                   var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
                   var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png');   
                   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position);
                   var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
                   alert ('lonlatTrans=> lat='+lonlatTransf.lat+' lon='+lonlatTransf.lon+'\nlonlat=>'+lonlat+'\nposition=>'+position);
                   var lonlat = lonlatTransf.transform(proj4326, map.getProjectionObject());
                   var markerslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
                   markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon));
                   map.addLayer(markerslayer);
               });
               map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
           }
       </script>
     </head>  

     <body onload="init()">
       <h1 id="title">MousePosition Control</h1>
       <div id="tags">coordinate</div>
       <p>Click on map and create marker</p>
       <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
       <div id="coords"></div>
       <div id="lonlatTG"></div>
       <div id="lonlatTrans"></div><br/>
       <p>
       see how, even though we did NOT transform [lonlat],
       <br/>it was nevertheless transformed
       </p>
       <div id="lonlatDouble"></div>

     </body>
   </html>
   ```

there is something that you need to be aware of regarding the TRANSFORM method for LonLat as used in this simple example: when you apply [    .transform(projection1, projection2)   ] to any LonLat, ALL LonLat objects are transformed.

play around with the order of certain commands and you will see what i mean.

for draggable markers, [this example has it all](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html)

Comment: Are you aware of fact that in your example, you are creating new layer "Markers" for every newly added marker? That's not very nice. Better solution is to create this once in a block above. Otherwise, it is very nice solution, thank you for that.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.  slipped under the radar.  tks for the headsup!

Comment: Hi, care to explain the differences between the different lon lat you are retrieving? Thanks

Comment: @rikket i didnt quite understand your question - could you please be a little more specific?  do you mean the difference between lonlat pairs and their projections?